# How to check a video has sound or not in Android?

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, mp4, textureview, android-textureview

I am using a TextureView with a MediaPlayer to play an mp4 video from a url. Is there any way I can programatically check if the video I am playing has sound?

Edit: I'm using API 14, so I don't have access to the MediaPlayer method getTrackInfo

Many Thanks

Answer (score 5):

In API level 16 or later, the `MediaPlayer` class has a [`getTrackInfo`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#getTrackInfo()) method that returns a [`TrackInfo[]`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.TrackInfo.html). You could then call `getTrackType` for each element in the array and see if you get `MEDIA_TRACK_TYPE_AUDIO`.

Comment: Ah yes, however I am using api 14, so this is not available for me :( Cheers anyway though

Comment: @Userrrrrrrrr did you find a way to do it for api 14?