# Fastest way to check if Video File have Following MetaData?

Tags: android, file, android-file, android-ffmpeg, mediametadataretriever

There are Number of ways to check video file Meta data , using [FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever](https://github.com/wseemann/FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever)(Slow but reliable) and using Native **MediaMetadataRetriever**(Slow and not reliable).

There are number of question answered in SO for same purpose to get MetaData using FFMPEG or Native Media api , like [Q1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31606331/how-to-check-a-video-has-sound-or-not-in-android) , [Q2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35475619/how-to-video-record-with-specific-sound-programmatically-in-android) , [Q3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8050686/how-to-get-all-media-infometadata-of-video-source) but they are not solving my problem.

### My Problem:

Get following meta data from file(Video) of android directory:

- Video have Sound/Audio or not?
- Creation date and time
- thumbnail of video file

Kindly let me know if you have any suggestion or code samples would be big help.

Answer (score 0):

**when i want check video has audio or not that time i created this method. method return True if Video has Audio otherwise False**

*just you pass Context and Uri of Your video file*

```
private boolean setHasAudioOrNot(JoinVideoActivity activity, Uri uri) {
    MediaMetadataRetriever retriever = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
    retriever.setDataSource(activity.getApplicationContext(),uri);
    Log.e("Command","audiohas?? " +retriever.extractMetadata(16));
    return retriever.extractMetadata(16) != null;
}
```

Comment: What if the file has no metadata? Then it will return `IllegalArgumentException `

Comment: if input file is file than it must have metadata if not than we can't use this method @ClassA

Comment: `if input file is file than it must have metadata` not all encoders add metadata, If you use this in your application you will most definitely get `IllegalArgumentException`. The question - `Fastest way to check if Video File have Following MetaData?` - In your answer you don't check if the file has the metadata, you assume the metadata is available.

Comment: hey buddy this snippet put in try and catch block  if occur exception than handle so we save from crash

Comment: Yes, I know that, buddy. Even if you put this method in a `try/catch`, you still don't answer the question OP asked, `check if Video File have Following MetaData`. You currently check if a file has audio using metadata, you don't check if the metadata is available.

Comment: hey bro please read this line carefully --> 
when i want check video has audio or not that time i created this method. method return True if Video has Audio otherwise False <<<< my answer only for check video has audio or not okk